# How to deploy static files in Django before hosting it anywhere?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Django application which needs to be deployed. Currently, I am not using Heroku or a Linux server to deploy it. However, I am trying to follow along with the Django checklist and ensure whether if it's ready to be deployed.

I had done the following in my settings.py module:

1. Set DEBUG = False
2. Allowed_Hosts = ['*']
3. STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"staticfiles")

This is my settings.py module:

```
"""
DJANGO PROJECT
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET KEY STORED IN ENVIRON VARIABLE'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',  #placing the Django app here.
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db', #name of the database.
        'USER' : '######',  
        'PASSWORD' : '######',  
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")  

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

After this, I typed the following command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now, when I run the server, my web app broke and none of the static files i.e CSS, media and JS are used. It's just plain HTML stuff.

The weird part is that, when I changed the **DEBUG mode to True**, the site works normally.

Can anyone explain the reason for this? How can I deploy a site when the DEBUG mode is set to True?

Comment: you checked it with local host? I mean in your system

Comment: Yes, the site works when the Debug mode is set to True. I want to set it to False and then make the site work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have this settings in your main urls

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you want to deploy the application in cloud server, there you have to create one static folder outside your main folder and place your static files there, so the collectstatic command will store your static files there.

Comment: But thats what the collectstatic command does right? I mean, when executing the command, a folder called staticfiles will be generated in the root/main folder and all the static files will be stored.

Comment: Collectstatic command is not needed in your development stage, it is needed only for production. The above code tells that take the static files from your static path when defug is true.

Comment: Oh. I wanted to use my app in production now. I used collectstatic and expected it to work when Debug was set to False but it appears that the static files are only viewed when Debug is True. Should I just create another folder and direct all the static files to it when debug is True and use staticfiles folder as a means to access all the static files when Debug equals to False?

Comment: Sorry bro, I haven't tried that way on my local server

Comment: But did your application work? Did you use collectstatic command and set Debug to False?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the Debug mode to False in production due to security issues.

Comment: you should test it in cloud

Comment: Sorry for asking, what do you mean by cloud? I am new to hosting a Django app so I am not familiar with the process.

Comment: you can deploy your app in any of the cloud servers(remote), Examples of server providers are heroku, linode, digital ocean, aws etc

Comment: Hmm, I think that might be the issue. As stated in my question, I am not using any cloud servers. Just trying to follow the checklist. Apart from the three points listed above in my question, what else do I need to be aware of before deploying it?

Comment: for cloud uploading there are plenty of guides available even with the providers, just follow the steps for configuring it. If the answer was useful, don't forget to tick :)